# How to use Hibernate SchemaExport to create DB schema at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, schema, schemaexport

I'm trying to use SchemaExport in my app to create the DB schema at application startup time.  I'm using Spring 3.2, and have a SessionFactory bean already defined in my Spring configuration file.

I'm trying to use it as follows:

```
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean session;

@Override
public void buildTable() throws Exception {
    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(session.getConfiguration());
    export.setDelimiter(";");
    export.execute(false, true, false, true);
}
```

where my LocalSessionFactoryBean is defined in my spring config file as:

```
 <!-- application datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource.jndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
</bean>

<!-- hibernate session -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource.jndi" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:domain/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, when I try to run the method, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No local DataSource found for configuration - 'dataSource' property must be set on LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.configure(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:263)
```

I've tried to trace the problem, and it appears that when the SchemaExport tries to write the schema to the DB, it creates a new LocalSessionFactory:

from org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory (edited for clarity):

```
private static ConnectionProvider initializeConnectionProviderFromConfig(String providerClass) {
    ConnectionProvider connections;
        connections = (ConnectionProvider) ReflectHelper.classForName( providerClass ).newInstance();
    return connections;
}
```

where providerClass = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider

So, instead of using the already existing ConnectionProvider as defined in my SessionFactory bean, it tries to create a new one.

How can I use an existing Spring configured SessionFactory / ConnectionProvider / Hibernate Configuration object in SchemaExport?  Is there something else I have to do to set up/configure SchemaExport in order to use it within my app?

Comment: Is it a web application? How do you run buildTable()? Are you sure your application is able to read your jndi when you're running buildTable()? Would you consider using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been required not to use `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto`, which is what is requiring my need to use SchemaExport now.  What is `buildTable()`?  I don't see that method anywhere on the API docs for SchemaExport.

Comment: @YoriKusanagi - And yes - it is a web application.

Comment: buildTable() is your method "public void buildTable() throws Exception" how do you run it? Is a jUnit or main method or a service...?

Comment: buildTable() is called during a bean-initialization process (ie: init-method="buildTable()").  A lot of code between the init-method and the call to buildTable(), but it is essentially run once the SessionFactory bean is defined, and before the TransactionManager bean is defined (ie: the TransactionManager bean - not listed here - depends on the bean which executes buildTable, which is dependent on SessionFactory)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dataSource is setup wrong.

Here's a Spring + Hibernate 3 example: http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_3_and_Hibernate_4_Example

For what it is worth, in your XML:

```
<!-- hibernate session -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" >
        <bean id="dataSource.jndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:domain/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Property (inner) beans like dataSource.jndi cannot be declared as "singleton" scope. They are prototype, if you want singleton scope, you have to create it as an external bean and set it using `ref` on the `property` markup.

Also, `<property name="dataSource">` causes a call to .getDataSource(), it doesn't matter that the bean is defined as dataSource.jndi. If you want to set the jndi attribute in the dataSource, you must do something like `<property name="dataSource.jndi">`.

Comment: Actually, I tried to cut and pasted things a little bit for clarity.  I might have forgotten to clean up some stuff a little.

Comment: I've edited the Spring configuration to be a little more clear.